# Using WITH clause with INSERT statement in POSTGRESQL

Tags: postgresql, insert, cte

I have a requirement in which I need to get one column from another table and insert that column data with some other data into another table.

Example:

If the cust_id='11' then I need to get the cust_code from cust table (let's say it returns cust_code='ABCD') and then use that cust_code with some other data to insert into table_1 like so:

```
WITH get_cust_code_for_cust_id AS (
    SELECT cust_code FROM cust WHERE cust_id=11
)

INSERT INTO public.table_1(
    cust_code, issue, status, created_on)
    VALUES (SELECT cust_code FROM get_cust_code_for_cust_id, 'New Issue', 'Open', current_timestamp)
```

But this query does not work as we haven't called the get_cust_code_for_cust_id query.

My preference is some query with WITH clause but any other answer will also be appreciated.

Comment: What error messages are you getting?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(Not tested in Postgres) Is this what you need?

```
INSERT INTO public.table_1(cust_code, issue, status, created_on)
SELECT cust_code, 'New Issue', 'Open', current_timestamp 
FROM cust 
WHERE cust_id=11
```